# Using reflection to cast unknown object to generic class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting

I have a method which takes an object as a parameter. Within that method I walk through that objects properties with reflection. Some properties are of a generic class type. I like to read a property of that generic class property, but I cannot cast it to a generic class.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class GenericClass<T>: BaseClass
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClassA: GenericClass<DerivedClassA>
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClassB: GenericClass<DerivedClassB>
{
    public string B { get; set; }
}

public class ReflectingClass: BaseClass
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DerivedClassA DerA { get; set; }
    public DerivedClassB DerB { get; set; }
}

public static void Reflecting(object obj)
{
    var t = GetType(obj)
    foreach (var pi in t.GetProperties())
    {
        if (obj.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(GenericClass<>)
        {
            var genClassObjProperty = ((GenericClass<T>)obj).Description; // Error, cannot do this at all !!!
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is for the code to walk to the properties and whatever the derived class actually is get the Description property of the GenericClass it is derived from.

I am using a generic class, because elsewhere in the code I call methods by their derived class and get the proper class type without resorting to all kinds of cast and passing types. I.e:

```cs
DerivedClassA.DoSomething()
```

instead of

```cs
BaseClass.DoSomething<DerivedClassA>()
```

or

```cs
BaseClass.DoSomething(type derivedClassType)
```

Comment: I am totally missing what you are trying to do and why generics are needed here.

Comment: Looks XY. Why are you trying to use reflection to access a property? What's the bigger picture?

Comment: Tried to make the example as basic as possible, but apparantly too basic: I use reflection in a base class for logging purposes and it does not know which type of object it gets. Why I use generics is mentioned in the post above.

Comment: Doing such an expensive thing as reflection _for logging purposes_ seems a bit over-the-top to me. Are you using a logging-framework? NLog, log4net, Serilog, Microsoft logging ... ?

Comment: What does `GetType` return? Is it some static method?

Comment: Not that type of logging, but I wanted to keep the question short and simple. I have a few hundred different classes derived from the generic class. I do not want to check the object parameter against every derived class type when all I want to get is the property of the generic class. So again: when a method takes an object as a parameter, how do you cast it to a generic class to get a property of that generic class?

Comment: GetType() gets the current type of the class it is called in. The method Reflecting() resides inside a base class, so it returns that base class type or the type of a class derived from the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
public static void Reflecting(object obj)
{
    foreach (var pi in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (pi.PropertyType.BaseType.IsGenericType
            && pi.PropertyType.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
            == typeof(GenericClass<>))
        {
            var propValue = pi.GetValue(obj);
            if (propValue != null)
            {
                var description = propValue.GetType()
                    .GetProperty("Description").GetValue(propValue);
                Console.WriteLine(description);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I think this is what you need.

Comment: Yes, thank you very very much! You made my day. This is exactly what I needed. Never occured to me to reflect the property of the generic class as well. Awesome and again thanks! Wish I could upvote you with a thousand points, but alas still under the threshold to be able to cast an upvote.